# Azure Devops Pipeline Question .NET Core Angular application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I used the Azure Portal to create a devops project. The portal created a devops project for me and used the .net core 2.2 razor pages template and deployed that successfully.

After that initial deployment, I decided to upgrade it to .NET Core 3.0 and use Angular in the project instead of using Razor Pages.

I added swagger as well since I am going to create some APIs.

I modified the Pipeline to include npm to install all the node modules and I had to add it to the drop folder for when I did the release pipeline.

After updating my release definition, I fired off a build and it deployed successfully (I disabled the functional test since it checks for the name of the site in the title).

However, whenever I visit the site, I am getting a 500 error but can still access the swagger page, so I at least know the api and back-end is running fine.

I go into Kudu and see that my files are all there but the .js, .css, .js.map, .css files were not in the correct place.

The folder structure I see in Kudu goes like this,

D:\home\site\wwwroot\

in the wwwroot directory, I have all my files as well as other directories. All my .js, .css, etc.. files are in the wwwroot folder.

However, I have another wwwroot directory within my wwwroot directory.

If I move all my front-end scripts and style sheets and images to that directory and only leave my index.html in the root directory, the front-end will load and fire off when I hit the site.

So my question is, how can I modify my release process so that all the files go in the correct location so that I don't have to manually go into kudu and move them myself?[Screenshot of directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlKM2.png)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "aspnet_core_dotnet_core": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": true,
            "extractCss": true,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "aspnet_core_dotnet_core:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "aspnet_core_dotnet_core:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "aspnet_core_dotnet_core:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": ["styles.css"],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": ["src/assets"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aspnet_core_dotnet_core-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "aspnet_core_dotnet_core:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "aspnet_core_dotnet_core"
}
```

Comment: Can you share with us your angular.json file ?

Comment: Try adding a "Command Line" task to your release to automate moving the files to the desired folder.

Comment: @wessamyaacob sure, this is my angular.json file

Comment: Perfect , also if it possible the .net core Setup file

Answer (score 0):

If your build pipeline produces a zipped artifacts. You need add an extract files task in release pipeline to unzip the artifacts in order to perform the copy file task.You can take 3 steps to copy the files to your target directory.

1.Add "Extract files" task to unzip the build file
[image]

2.Add "Copy files" task to copy the .js, .css, .js.map, .css files to your target folder
[image]

3.Add "Archive files" to zip your file after finishing the above steps
[image]

Comment: @TJ Lopez Have you solved your problem, if you have any problems, feel free to tell us